# ellipsize with multiple text views

Tags: android, textview

I have ListView row implemented as LinearLayout. There are 3 TextViews inside oriented horizontally and aligned to the left. Normally a row looks like this:
`0 Normal Nickname 18.12.2013`
But sometimes the nickname text is very long, so I want it to be ellipsized when all three TextViews don't feet on the screen. I want text to look like this:
`0 Ridiculously Long Ni... 18.12.2013`
but I get this instead:
`0 Ridiculously Long Nickname 18.12.2`

Layout

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/cmnt_row_rating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/cmnt_row_author"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cmnt_row_rating"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:lines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/cmnt_row_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cmnt_row_author"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:lines="1"
/>
```

Is there a way to achieve effect I need?

Comment: see my answer. It will sort all your issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..  Use `android:singleLine="true"` for that `TextView` and also equally space for each `TextView` use `android:layout_weight="1"` .For `weight` you need to use `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/cmnt_row_rating"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="left"
/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/cmnt_row_author"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:lines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/cmnt_row_date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:lines="1"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: well, this do the trick with ellipses, but makes all textviews the same width and I don't need that

Comment: @Sergi0 then use `android:layout_weight="1"` for only one `TextView` for other remove it and use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: ok, this one is better, but it gets date to be aligned to the right, cause nickname takes all the free space.

Comment: ok, accepting yours, cause it closer then others. can't accept ems version cause rows have different width.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `android:ems=""` like this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/cmnt_row_rating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/cmnt_row_author"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cmnt_row_rating"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:lines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:ems="3"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/cmnt_row_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cmnt_row_author"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:lines="1"
/>
```

I have set it 3. Change it according to your need.

Comment: this makes middle part always take the same space, no matter it 3 or 10 characters long: `0 Short_____________18.12.2013` instead of `0 Short_18.12.2013`

Answer (score 0):

use `android:maxEms` attribute to limit characters in your `TextView`. change maxEms value according to your need.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cmnt_row_author"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cmnt_row_rating"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:lines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxEms="4"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
/>
```

Comment: the problem is that text looks like this `0 Ridiculously L...______18.12.2013`instead looking like this `0 Ridiculously L..._18.12.2013`. So it truncates the middle view, but it still takes all the space.